# LINUX - The build of my Unity game crashes after a few hours - Receiving unhandled NULL exception

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, ubuntu, exception, crash

### **Description of the problem:**

The build crashes and closes itself after a few hours (usually in a range between 4 and 12 hours), printing this message in the log:

```
Receiving unhandled NULL exception

#0  0x00000000ff382c in std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
#1  0x0000000102c983 in std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
#2  0x0000000102d9c5 in std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
#3  0x00000000c07080 in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#4  0x00000000c0719f in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#5  0x00000000c07522 in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#6  0x00000000c07798 in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#7  0x00000000c078db in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#8  0x00000000cb8d90 in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#9  0x007f29dc9ff182 in start_thread
#10 0x007f29dc926b1f in clone
```

### **Tech specs:**

- Unity: 2018.4.28 LTS (running on Windows)
- OS: Ubuntu 19.04 LTS optimized for UDOO Bolt by UDOO team (https://www.udoo.org/docs-bolt/Operating_Systems/Linux/index.html)
- Hardware: UDOO Bolt v8 (https://shop.udoo.org/udoo-bolt-v8.html and https://www.udoo.org/docs-bolt/Introduction/Introduction.html)

### **Tests done (not fixing the bug):**

- To separate the logs of my threads (since I have a few threads), so each thread prints the debug on a different file not using the Player.log because it is used by the main thread.
- To create a build without the threads.
- To maintain the hardware temperature very low, around 45° avoiding high temp on CPU and GPU.
- To disable the AMD virtualization from the BIOS.
- To enable the "Disable HW Statistics" checkbox in the Player Settings -> Other, since I found that this could be responsible for the error "Curl error 6: Could not resolve host: cdp.cloud.unity3d.com", whose the stacktrace is very similar to the one of the crash  (to see the stacktrace I set it to Full in the Player Settings -> Other -> Logging):

Curl error 6: Could not resolve host: cdp.cloud.unity3d.com

```
 #0 std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
 #1 ???
 #2 std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
 #3 std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
 #4 std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
 #5 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #6 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #7 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #8 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #9 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #10 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
 #11 start_thread
 #12 clone
```

### **Gathered info from previous tests:**

- Sometimes there is only the error  “Receiving unhandled NULL exception” after the crash, other times there is also the full stack trace.
- Sometimes the error “Receiving unhandled NULL exception” is separated from the stack trace by some other prints.
- Enabling the Full Log in Unity, precisely in Player Settings -> Other -> Logging, a print in the update (using debug.log) generates this stack trace (which is very similar to our exception, so I am guessing that “operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)” and the Vector are part of the Debug.Log and they are not linked to my problem):

DebugLog stacktrace

```
DebugLog from Update!

#0 std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
#1 std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector()
#2  (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,string,UnityEngine.Object)
#3 mono_print_method_from_ip
#4 mono_perfcounter_foreach
#5 mono_runtime_invoke
#6 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#7 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#8 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#9 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#10 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#11 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#12 operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&)
#13 ???
#14 __libc_start_main
#15 ???
```

- Only one time the stack trace was different:

"Different Receiving unhandled NULL exception"

```
Receiving unhandled NULL exception 

#0  0x007f1056492bf4 in nouveau_drm_screen_create 
#1  0x007f1056495aa0 in nouveau_drm_screen_create 
#2  0x007f10561a878f in nouveau_drm_screen_create 
#3  0x007f1056235c84 in nouveau_drm_screen_create 
#4  0x007f1056235f87 in nouveau_drm_screen_create 
#5  0x000000010dcf2a in std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector() 
#6  0x000000010f1169 in std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector() 
#7  0x00000000b01116 in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) 
#8  0x000000010ef244 in std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > > >::~vector() 
#9  0x00000000924e9b in std::pow(float, float) 
#10 0x000000009209e2 in std::pow(float, float) 
#11 0x00000000920b19 in std::pow(float, float) 
#12 0x00000000cb8d90 in operator new[](unsigned long, std::nothrow_t const&) 
#13 0x007f105b6ed182 in start_thread 
#14 0x007f105b614b1f in clone
```

- I noticed these things intercepting the signals received by the game:
  Every 5 seconds (approximately), 7 signals SIGPWR  has been received,followed by 7 signals SIGXCPU.
  When the game crashes, the signals SIGSEGV, SIGABRT has been received, followed by a lot of SIGSTOP, ending with SIGABRT and SIGPIPE.
  This is the last part of the log of the signals.    The columns use this order:
  "Epoch", "Time of Signal", "Name", "PID", "Signal", "Signaling Process Name"

Handled signals log

```
1601585247770866   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585247770920   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585247770934   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585247771012   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585247771033   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585247771101   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585247771112   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585247790047   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585247790085   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585247790098   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585247790155   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585247790171   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585247790234   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585247790245   Thu Oct  1 22:47:27 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585252704451   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585252704506   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585252704570   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585252704591   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585252704653   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585252704673   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585252704685   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPWR    MyGame.x86_
1601585252723584   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585252723644   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585252723698   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585252723716   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585252723799   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585252723819   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585252723829   Thu Oct  1 22:47:32 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGXCPU   MyGame.x86_
1601585253349839   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSEGV   MyGame.x86_
1601585253360946   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGABRT   MyGame.x86_
1601585253471368   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471658   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame:cs0   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471690   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame:sh0   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471704   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame:sh1   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471731   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame:sh2   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471752   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame:sh3   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471763   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame:sh4   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471774   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame:sh5   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471859   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471890   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471904   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471917   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471937   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471953   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471968   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471980   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253471990   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472015   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472027   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472043   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472059   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472074   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472084   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472103   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472121   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472136   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472150   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472165   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472176   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472194   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472208   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472223   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472246   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472275   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472291   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472316   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472333   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472348   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472363   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472391   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472408   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472418   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472435   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472451   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472482   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585253472593   Thu Oct  1 22:47:33 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGSTOP   gdb
1601585254227807   Thu Oct  1 22:47:34 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGCHLD   gdb
1601585254227927   Thu Oct  1 22:47:34 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGABRT   MyGame.x86_
1601585254309322   Thu Oct  1 22:47:34 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPIPE   MyGame.x86_
1601585254309342   Thu Oct  1 22:47:34 2020 CEST        MyGame.x86_   30851   SIGPIPE   MyGame.x86_
```

### **Resources used:**

I used the following script in order to intercept the signals, running it with the command “sudo stap myscript.stp”.

```
#! /usr/bin/env stap

probe signal.send {
  if ((isinstr(pid_name, "MyGame"))) {
      printf("%10d   %-34s   %-10s   %5d   %-7s   %s\n",
      gettimeofday_us(), tz_ctime(gettimeofday_s()),
      pid_name, sig_pid, sig_name, execname());
  }
}


probe begin {
  printf("systemtap script started at: %s\n\n", tz_ctime(gettimeofday_s()));
  printf("%50s%-18s\n", "",  "Signaled Process");
  printf("%-10s   %-34s   %-10s   %5s   %-7s   %s\n",
    "Epoch", "Time of Signal", "Name", "PID", "Signal", "Signaling Process Name");
  printf("---------------------------------------------------------------");
  printf("---------------------------------------------------------------");
  printf("\n");
}

probe end {
  printf("\n");
}
```

### **Doubts**

- Are the signals received during the crash the cause of it? Or are they a consequence?
- Could “Curl error 6: Could not resolve host: cdp.cloud.unity3d.com” be the problem?
- The crash seems caused by a segmentation fault. Is my game that is generating this segmentation fault? Or could it be a library or something else? How can I understand it?

### **What I am trying to do (but I’m currently stuck):**

- <del>I would like to create a dump analyzing it with a debugger.</del>
- I would like to find a method to catch the not handled exception, making easier the research of the problem.

## **UPDATE x1:**

I was able to create the core dump. You can find the full log here:
https://pastebin.com/1Bm70rNd

While the native stacktrace of the exception is:

```
/home/username0/MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/x86_64/libmonobdwgc-2.0.so(+0xd5378) [0x7f644c157378]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x15540) [0x7f645dd08540]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xcb) [0x7f645db463eb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x12b) [0x7f645db25899]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xd341e6]
/home/username0/MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/x86_64/libmonobdwgc-2.0.so(+0x14ea2e) [0x7f644c1d0a2e]    /home/username0/MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame_Data/MonoBleedingEdge/x86_64/libmonobdwgc-2.0.so(+0x5be11) [0x7f644c0dde11]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x15540) [0x7f645dd08540]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xb23e60]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xff382c]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0x102c983]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0x102d9c5]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xc07080]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xc0719f]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xc07522]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xc07798]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xc078db]
MyGame_Game/Game/MyGame.x86_64() [0xcb8d90]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x9669) [0x7f645dcfc669]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x43) [0x7f645dc222b3]
```

Searching online about this exception I found it could be a bug of Mono and/or a driver compatibility issue. Now I'm updating Ubuntu from 19.04 to 20.04 to try the amdgpu-pro drivers (instead of amdgpu included in Ubuntu) since I can't find the amdgpu-pro driver for Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: If it always happens after a certain amount of time my first guess would be: Are you maybe running out of RAM (or similar)? Did you [profile](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) your app? If something runs for hours maybe somewhere you are allocating something you never give free? E.g. a common mistake is to create or download new Textures (or in general assets) on runtime that are never destroyed since they are not automatically GC collected.

Comment: These days I tried to check the RAM usage, and when the game crashes a lot of RAM is not used, so I suppose it's not running out of memory.
Then I thought the problem could be caused by the GPU memory usage but my GPU has shared memory so it should use the RAM, and since I have a lot of not used RAM it should not be the GPU either.

Comment: I did not profile the game for many hours because I had some trouble attaching the Unity Profiler from my Windows Computer to the game on Linux, and even if I could connect it to the build I could not use the editor because it's profiling the game. But, since every asset is located inside the build, and the RAM and the RAM usage seems pretty constant, I'm supposing that the problem is not related to the not GC collected objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found out that my problem was a Trail option of a particle.
While I was searching on the internet, I found other people saying the trail renderer could be the problem, but I didn't know I was using it since it was inside a particle (I have a few of them), so I was excluding this cause.

I also checked the driver compatibility issue, I updated to Ubuntu 20.04 and I installed the amdgpu-pro driver, but it didn't solve anything.

Hope this will be helpful.